# El filtraje con jquery.filter es muy lento

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, dom, filtro

estoy haciendo una web y tengo una lista con unos 8000 datos de texto, como son nombres, dni...
y Al hacer el filtrado con jquery usando .filter, si en el input escribo algo y luego lo borro, me carga todos los 8000 datos otra vez y hace que la web vaya lenta, como podría solucionar esto y hacer el filtrado mas rápido?? Muchas gracias, este es mi html:

```
 <span  id = "listaSocios" >
     {{#each socios}}
      <li style="display: none;">
       <span class="codigo-dropdown">{{codigo}}</span>
       <span class="nombre-dropdown">{{nombre}}</span>
       <span class="dni-dropdown">{{dni}}</span>
      </li>
    {{/each}}
 </span>
```

Y este mi javascript:

```
$(".input-codigo").on("keyup", function () {
    var value = $(this).val().toLowerCase();

    $("#listaSocios li").filter(function() {
      $(this).toggle($(this).text().toLowerCase().indexOf(value) > -1)
    });      
});
```

Comment: ¿Falta un return en la función que se le pasa a filter, no?

Comment: No, sin el me funciona bien pero lento

Comment: Creo que usar [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) sería más adecuado porque tiene esa funcionalidad, entre muchas otras.

Comment: Ya lo uso pero tarda mucho al pintar muchos datos (8000)